# Div / Class hides on Html page launch

Tags: jquery, html, class, hidden

I am having a headache to understand what is wrong with my html page.

I have got different Divs and Class that appear for one second (When I launch the page for the first time) then, they hide.

But if i make a scroll or any move on the page, all the divs / class appear.

Same happens with the footer ( But only on this page, other pages of the site are not impacted )

Here is a link to the page :  http://www.dentalbel.be/test/produits.html

If anyone could help me, i'd be grateful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? Aside from the fact that they are all initially visible on the page, they seem to work fine on chrome after they disappear.  As a result I'm not particularly certain what you are asking for here.  Perhaps if you included some screenshots of your descriptions it might be easier to help.

Comment: I am using google chrome. It does the same thing with safari. It is only when the page loads that some divs and the footer are hidden. After a scroll on the page, everything works fine. What i am asking is the reason for my div and footer to hide when the page is loaded for the first time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First try removing the `<center>` tag because it is [not supported in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp) and might be distorting the images on page load. Use the [Bootstrap `text-center` class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) CSS instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have removed the <center> but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using masonry? also why are you using divs instead of `<ul>`,

The idea to use masonry affect some behavior ando one of them is the scroll,

I suggest to change the masonry tiles to a clean markup, css, js, and change the animation using jquery

Comment: Thank you. Masonry was already included in the template. But if i remove it, all the divs (images) will be unorganized. I have tried using <ul> but i don't know how to align all the divs in different columns and being able to use the 'filter' option. What would you recommend as an alternative to masonry ?

Comment: Ok I get it, maybe take i little time try to organize all the markup, css and adding javascript, but this is the idea: try to use [link] (http://callmenick.com/post/simple-responsive-tabs-javascript-css) just for tabs navigation, on each panel you have to add the images just using `<ul class="products"><li>`, and in the css, `.products li { display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; padding: 10px; }`

Comment: Ok! I will give it a try. Thank you